# How to check current stock remaining

Tags: python, django

I am struggling to get current remaining stock in my inventory application.
I have written code to calculate remaining quantity but it calculates based on purchased quantity only. I want to add total sold quantity and find the difference between purchased and total sold quantity.
How do I calculate total sold quantity and calculate the remaining stock.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Stock(models.Model):
    sold_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name

    @property
    def get_difference(self):
        total = self.product.quantity-self.sold_quantity
        return total
```

Views.py

```
def add_sales(request):
    form = AddSalesForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddSalesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.product.quantity -= instance.sold_quantity
            instance.save()
            return redirect('stock_details')
    contex = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'stockmgmt/add_sales.html', contex)
```

templates

```
{% extends 'stockmgmt/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form method="GET">
<a href="{% url 'add_sales' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Add Sales</a>
<p>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Purchased Qty</th>
            <th>Sold Qty</th>
            <th>Remaining Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in stocks %}  
        
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.product.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.product.category}}</td>
            <td>{{item.product.quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{item.sold_quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{item.get_difference}}</td>
            <td>{{item.product.price}}</td>
            

            <td><a href="{% url 'delete_sales' item.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}



    </table>
</form>

{% endblock  %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the existing stock after each order

for ex.

opening stock = 100
current stock = 100

after first order of 10 qty

opening stock = 100
current stock = current stock - order qty = 100 - 10 = 90

after second order of 5  qty

opening stock = 100
current stock = current stock - order qty = 90 - 5 = 85

if i purchase or add new stock the current stock will be updated

after adding 50 qty

current stock = current stock + purchase qty = 85 + 50 = 135

you can have  a log table (Model) for income and outgoing of stock for tracking

hope you understand the concept i'm trying to explain